# How does Sonatype authentication of packages work?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Specifically, how do I tell Sonatype that I have a new key pair?

I publish my PGP public key to a pool, and sign my artifacts with my private key. If I upload those artifacts to Sonatype Nexus, how does it authenticate the packages? On what basis does it distinguish packages signed by me from packages signed by someone else?

I imagine there's a step where I tell Sonatype what my public key is, but I can't remember ever doing that and I can't see it in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are asking about uploading your artifacts to the Central Repository via OSSRH. The [current user documentation for OSSRH](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) details that you need to sign your packages with GPG as you are aware. Uploading is done via OSSRH and the username you have there. The authentication of the packages is done via your user credential and then the package signature are verified against public key pools. AFAIK it does NOT check if the packages are signed by you but rather just that they are signed with a publicly available, valid key and you can only upload with your username/password.

Update: The benefit of requiring signed artifacts is that upon download the artifacts can be checked upon for the signature and checksum and you can therefore ensure that you only download packages as originally submitted by the uploader and have not been tempered with on Central or in transport to your server. Related to that it is a good idea to connect to Central via https as offered as a cheap service by Sonatype and used by default in Nexus Pro.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question: What benefit is signing of the package if any old signature will do?

Comment: Updated the answer. Hth.